# Does Visual Studio 2010 support something like Eclipse's "Generate delegate methods"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, eclipse, visual-studio-2010, resharper

Eclipse allows us to define a class as:

```
interface MyInterface {
    void methodA();
    int methodB();
}

class A : MyInterface {
    MyInterface myInterface;
}
```

and then with this "Generate delegate methods", it will implement all needed methods for the interface, redirecting their logic to myInterface's methods:

```
class A : MyInterface {
    MyInterface myInterface;

    public void methodA() {
        myInterface.methodA();
    }

    public int methodB() {
        return myInterface.methodB();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to accomplish the same with VS2010?
And with R#?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Resharper you can do this.

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_generation.html

> **Generate Delegating Members**
>
> Delegating members provides a means to encapsulate some behavior or publish methods of a class's field through the class's own interface. Specify fields and their methods, and ReSharper will generate wrapping methods in the current class.

This is a great feature that we use all the time.  There are a few ways to access it but what I do is hit `ALT-INS` which brings up the `Generate` context menu.  A few items down on the list is `Delegating members`.  Then you get a tree from which you select the fields (objects) you want to delegate to and which delegating properties/methods you want to create.  Very quick and easy and works great.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't explain how to accomplish it. Have you ever done it, by chance?

Comment: Ah, found it under Code Generation. This was obvious :(. Ty

Comment: @devoured elysium, yeah, I use this feature all the time.  I'll edit my answer to add more info.